# After installing ubuntu 18.04 LTS my battery drains

Tags: drivers, nvidia, power-management, battery

I am having a problem with my Dell laptop, in that after installing Ubuntu 18.04LTS (from windows 8), my battery drains very fast, without doing anything heavy. When I had Windows I could use my laptop about 7 hours, now I can barely use it for 3 hours.

I use Dell laptop, with Intel core i5, and GeForce GT 750M graphics card.

What I can do to debug/solve this?

Edit - I saw on "Details" page that it uses "Graphics: intel Haswell Mobile"